# Get words inside parentheses

Tags: php

How do i echo words if they are between (), here is my example:

```
<?php
$text = "(test1) ignore this right here (test2) ignore (test3)";
Echo get_texts_between("()",$text);
?>
```

the output should be:
test1 test2 test3

Comment: can there be other things than words between ()? Like a dot or comma?

Answer (score 2):

You can use preg_match for that:

```
$text = "(test1) ignore this right here (test2) ignore (test3)";
$pattern = '/\(([a-z0-9]+)\)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);

echo implode(' ', $matches[1]);
```

Note this only matches `a-z` and `0-9` in the `()`. Which would match your example sentence. If you would match only e.g. 4 letters and 1 number or when there may be other characters inside the group you'll have to add more examples of what exactly you would like to match in your OP.

Comment: @arnoudhgz Why? doesn't it work?? Your comment would have made sense if it didn't work for sure. I also write English without a spellchecker. Should I also enable a spellchecker when posting on SO?

Comment: Maybe it works, but I don't want to test it for you. I was actually trying to solve this case and test my answer. And you just quick post an answer without testing it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works without testing it. I neither tested whether `var_dump` works. So what?

Comment: Ok, why do you say: 'Note this isn't tested'

Comment: Removed the test phrase. There might have been a typo in it which I would solve for OP. The thing is: I don't setup a testcase for every answer I give here on SO (when I am confident enough I get it right) :-)

Comment: @arnoudhgz there can be plenty of testcases, PeeHaa covered most of them, his answer is a hint, not a complete solution (and it shouldn't be).

Comment: @webarto, I know, but PeeHaa already changed his solution. First he mentioned that he didn't test his answer.

Comment: @arnoudhgz See the revision. I didn't change the solution. BTW I still haven't tested it ;)

Comment: actually I should not comment anymore, but you are right... I should have say: changed his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do with replacing the parts ([`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace)) you are not interested in with a single space:

```
echo preg_replace('~^\(|\)[^\(]*\(|\)$~', ' ', $text);
```

This is with a regular expression matching either the single open bracket at the beginning of the string `^\(`, the close and open bracket part within the string `\)[^\(]*\(`or the single closing bracket at the end of the string `\)$`.

If you do not need the trailing slashes, add a simple `trim` to it. Alternatively there is also `preg_split`:

```
echo implode(' ', preg_split('~^\(|\)[^\(]*\(|\)$~', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

but it's getting a bit complex in one line I'd say. The pattern is the same btw.